# Checking if content of an array is all integers

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm working on a sorting code. I would like to check if my array contains non integers. Here is my code:

```
array = Array.new
puts "Please enter your 3 digits."
3.times do
  str = gets.chomp.to_i
  array.push str.to_i
end
if array.is_a?(Numeric) == false
  puts "Error, only use Integers please!"
else
  print "Here are your sorted numbers: #{array.sort}"
end
```

Comment: In the future, please be more clear about exactly what error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you have above your `array` is guaranteed to contain integers since you are converting your input to Integers using `to_i`:

```
array.push str.to_i
```

You are in fact doing it twice.  When you read the string from STDIN and when you push it onto the array.

You need to check to see if the input is a string before you call `to_i`.

```
3.times do
  str = gets.chomp
  # code to verify if str is numeric.
  array.push str
end
```

There are lots of ways to implement that code depending on what your requirements are.  Integers only could be done like this:

```
unless str =~ /^\d+$/
  puts "Error, only use Integers please!"
  exit
end
```

The above would work for any positive integers, but not negative.  It would also fail if you allowed decimals.  But it gives you an idea.  Search "ruby check if string is a number" and you'll find a lot more info.

Also note that the above fails as soon as it finds a non integer instead of waiting till after.

Answer (score 3):

You clearly can't `gets.chomp.to_i` (or the equivalent, `gets.to_i`), because that will only return integers. You therefore need to see if the string represents a number before adding it to the array.

You can do that with a regular expression or confirm that [Kernel::Integer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) does not raise an exception (and catch it if it does).

A regular expression that would work is simply:

```
str =~ /^-?\d+$/
```

after

```
str = gets.chomp.strip
```

To use `Kernel::Integer`:

```
def integer?(str)
  begin
    Integer(str)
  rescue ArgumentError
    return false
  end
  str.to_i
end
```

For example,

```
integer?("-33")  #=> -33
integer?("-x33") #=> false
integer?(" 33 ") #=>  33
integer?("33\n") #=>  33
```

The last two examples show that you can drop `chomp.strip` from `gets.chomp.strip` when using this approach.

If you wish to allow integers or floats, change the regular expression to:

```
/^-?\d+\.?\d*$/
```

or check to see that [Kernel::Float](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) raises an exception:

```
def float?(str)
  begin
    Float(str)
  rescue ArgumentError
    return false
  end
  str.to_f
end  

float?("-33.4")   #=> -33.4 
float?("-33")     #=> -33.0 
float?("x33.4")   #=> false 
float?(" 33.4\n") #=> 33.4
```